# HTTP Service not accessible through Virtual IP in Azure Ubuntu Classic VM

Tags: azure

I have a http service listening in port 52205 in a azure ubuntu VM. The VM is assigned with a Network Security Group with the inbound and outbound values set as in the snapshot. Even then I couldn't telnet or access the http endpoints from my local machine.

[image]

Comment: Are you create a Classic VM?

Comment: Yes, it is a Classic VM

Comment: Azure classic VM should open ports in Endpoints, same as NSG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, you should open port in **Endpoints**:

[image]

Comment: Okay,   Do you mind explaining the difference between endpoints and N/W Security Group?

Comment: @Minisha Different Azure modules, classic VM use endpoints, resource module VM use NSG, also you can add NSG to a classic VM.

Comment: When I tried to create a Endpoint getting this error:  "Failed to update endpoint 'ipos-52205' on virtual machine 'blockchain-research'. Unable to create virtual machine 'blockchain-research': 'Endpoint ACLs and Network Security Groups are not supported on the same deployment. The following roles have endpoint ACLs: blockchain-research. These roles have a Network Security Group: blockchain-research.'."

Comment: Which means should I remove the N/W Security Group from the VM first?

Comment: @Minisha ACL and NSGs are not supported on the same VM instance, you can just add ports to endpoints, don't use ACL.

Comment: Okay, it works. Thank you. But overall azure is very confusing:( .